# PHP Search for Text/Data in Variable containing XML Data

Tags: php

I have XML data inside a variable.

I now need to search for a specific text inside this variable.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've been googling this but no good results :o/

The XML data looks like this:

```
<status>
<connection_status>successful</connection_status>
<operation_status>successful</operation_status>
<Options>
<data_2>
<data_7422731>
<id>7431</id>
<assetId>2</assetId>
<startDate>2013-03-05 11:00:00</startDate>
<endDate>2013-03-05 12:00:00</endDate>
</data_7422731>
</data_2>
</Options>
</status>
```

I need to search for a specified ID.

For example the id "7431"

Comment: Are you looking for a specific element? Or rather specific text-content?

Comment: Post your code. Show your efforts.

Comment: Can you show the code (structure of the XML file, what you are looking for and what you have tried)?

Comment: -1 for lack of clarity and lack of code

Comment: I have added the data structure. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this isn't quite XML related, but like others said, unless you provide more detail and code, there's not much help we can do.

This is a quick dirty fix in case you don't want to be bothered setting up an XML parser:

Edit: I updated the code to fix some tiny mistakes, and I turned it into a function so you can call it into any tag.

```
function findID($mystring,$tag)
{
    $begintag="<$tag>";
    $endtag = "</$tag>";
    $beginpos = strpos($mystring, $begintag);
    $endpos = strpos($mystring,$endtag );

    $length = $endpos - ($beginpos + strlen($beginpos) +1);

    $extractedvariable = substr($mystring, $beginpos + strlen($beginpos) +1, $length); 

    return $extractedvariable;
}
```

Usage example:

```
$data='<status>
            <connection_status>successful</connection_status>
            <operation_status>successful</operation_status>
            <Options>
            <data_2>
            <data_7422731>
            <id>7431</id>
            <assetId>2</assetId>
            <startDate>2013-03-05 11:00:00</startDate>
            <endDate>2013-03-05 12:00:00</endDate>
            </data_7422731>
            </data_2>
            </Options>
            </status>';

echo findID($data,'id');
```

I still recommend using an XML parser if you are going to use most of the tags in the variables or if you have multilevel XML.

Comment: It return blank ... what I want to do is tell it: "find text '7431' in $data variable"

Answer (score 2):

Use an [XML parser](http://php.net/simplexml) to [load the string to XML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php), then [get its children](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmliterator.getchildren.php) or use [XPATH](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) like:

```
/status/Options/data_2//id
```